# exit().remove() not working for Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: d3.js, stack, bar-chart

I am trying to plot stacked bar chart, it's rendering for first time perfectly. I have a select box on my page, and on change event of select item, I am again rendering it, but that time graph is not changing. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Please find following code which I am using.

Kindly help me to figure out where I am going wrong.

Appreciate your help!

```js
var svg;


function initializeChar(data){

 var chart_width     =   800;
 var chart_height    =   400;
 var color           =   d3.scaleOrdinal( d3.schemeCategory10 ); 
  
 // Stack Layout
 var stack           =   d3.stack().keys([
     'quoteCount', 'policyCount'
 ]);
 var stack_data      =   stack(data);

 // Create SVG Element
 if(selAgent == "All"){
 svg             =   d3.select("#chart")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", chart_width)
     .attr("height", chart_height);
 }
 
 update();
 
 function update(){
  
  // Scales
  var x_scale         =   d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(d3.range(data.length))
      .range([0, chart_width])
      .paddingInner(0.05);
  var y_scale         =   d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([
          0,
          d3.max( data, function(d){
              return d.quoteCount + d.policyCount;
          })
      ])
      .range([ chart_height, 0 ]);  
  
  // Groups
   var groups          =   svg.selectAll( 'g' )
      .data( stack_data )
      .enter()
      .append( 'g' )
      .style( 'fill', function( d, i ){
          return color( i );
      })
      .attr("class","g");
   
  // Rectangles
  var rect = groups.selectAll( 'rect' )
      .data(function( d ){       
          return d;
      });
  
  rect.exit().attr("class","exit").remove();
  
  rect.attr("x", function(d, i) {
           return x_scale(i);
       })
       .attr("y", function(d) {
           return y_scale(d[1]);
       })
       .attr("height", function(d) {
           return y_scale(d[0]) - y_scale(d[1]);
       })
       .attr("width", x_scale.bandwidth())
       .attr("class","update");
  
  var myr = rect.enter()
      .append("rect")
       .attr("x", function(d, i) {
           return x_scale(i);
       })
       .attr("y", function(d) {
           return y_scale(d[1]);
       })
       .attr("height", function(d) {
           return y_scale(d[0]) - y_scale(d[1]);
       })
       .attr("width", x_scale.bandwidth())
       .attr("class","rect");
  
  console.log(rect);
  
 }//end of update
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How many elements are in the groups variable each time? Use `groups.size()`, also see how many rects you are selecting, if it is zero, you can't exit anything.

Comment: In Groups element initially there are 11 elements but in change event when I am again calling it, then it has 0 elements. I am not sure if it’s not getting bind for next time. However on HTML page those existing Dom elements are not going away. And eventually I am seeing same graph.